# Visual Studio Editor falls back to Courier

Tags: visual-studio-2022

After a reboot, the Visual Studio editor fallbacks to Courier font. Does anyone have any idea of why this is happening and what you can do about it?

I'm using the following version of VS:
Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2022 (64-bit) - Version 17.1.3

I'm running the following version of Windows:
Windows 10 Enterprise, Version 21H2

Comment: Same problem here... After updating a separate installation of VS preview to latest release. Have you found a solution?

Comment: The "solution" for me was to reinstall Visual Studio...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be problem for some people, including myself. It is already reported at the [Visual Studio Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Cascadia-Mono-is-missing-and-VS-uses-cou/1679085). tl;dr - [this workaround](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Cascadia-Mono-is-missing-and-VS-uses-cou/1679085#T-N10015769) is the fastest - reinstall Cascadia Mono via choco.

They [changed the default font](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/weve-upgraded-the-ui-in-visual-studio-2022/#more-accessibility-and-flexibility-in-editor-fonts) in Visual Studio 2022 to Cascadia Mono.

To answer your question why this suddenly breaks - the root cause seeems unclear as of this moment, but that font gets corrupted or removed and VS reverts back to some other font, in my case Courier. Repairing Visual Studio or reinstalling the font is required.

Or even easier, if you like the prior default font more, Consolas, just use that.

Comment: Chocolatey package is broken too.. 

choco install cascadiamono
Chocolatey installed 0/1 packages. 1 packages failed.
 See the log for details (C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\logs\chocolatey.log).

Failures
 - cascadiamono - Unable to resolve dependency 'dotnet-aspnetcoremodule-v2'. Source(s) used: 'https://community.chocolatey.org/api/v2/'.

Answer (score 5):

Chocolatey package for Cascadia Code is broken. Install it the 'hard way'.

Go to this site :
https://github.com/microsoft/cascadia-code/releases

Download the newest Cascadia Code release here.

Install the regular and semi-bold ttf font for example by double clicking on those fonts after extracting the .zip file which is available for each release.

Restart VS 2022. You should now have Cascadia Code working again and avoid Courier font which is very unreadable for semi elderly coders like me. That font is way too "thin".